# Creating two users tables inside Firebase projects

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create two users table inside my Firebase project,one for teachers and one for students. But I don't exactly know how to do it. Can you please recommend me a resource or give me a clue on how doing this please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a NoSQL database. It is use JSON as the database. Here is an overview how to make 2 roots (tables) for each teachers and students. As you can see the JSON belows, I assume there are 2 tables, student and teacher. the `userUid` is the id that we get from the Firebase Authentication. The next nodes are the attributes/properties for that particular student/teacher.

```
my_project
   -student
      -userUid
         - name
         - type
         - email
         - id
      -userUid2
         - name
         - type
         - email
         - id2
   -teacher
      -userUid3
         - name
         - type
         - email
         - id3
      -userUid4
         - name
         - type
         - email
         - id4
```